# Subprocess no output in windows

Tags: subprocess, exe

I need to run an exe file with different parameters and write the output to a file. I tried the following script. After the program is running, the output file is empty. Tell me how to solve this problem

```
import subprocess
output_f = open('output.txt', 'a')
for i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}_":
    for j in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}_":
        program = 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/task2 (1).exe ' + i +" " +j;
        process = subprocess.Popen(program,stdout=output_f)
        code = process.wait()
output_f.close()
print(code)
```